# Contains statement in the LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want do something like this:

```
string test = alarmType;
db.Alarms.Where(alarmType.Contains(m => m.Type)).ToList();
```

But this doesn't work. How can I make such query? Is it the only way to use pure SQL?

UPD
I'm trying to find whether records is substring of the "test", not conversly.

Comment: I'm trying to find whether records is substring of the "test", not conversly.

Comment: Please edit your question with this clarification. Code with comment "doesn't work" looks meaningless therefore get downvoted. Also `asp.net-mvc` tag is redundant here.

Comment: @Fyodor Thank you, just a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reverse the condition:

```
var query = db.Alarms
    .Where(a => alarmType.Contains(a.Type))
    .ToList();
```

However, your code sample is confusing, if `alarmType` is a string i don't know what you're trying to achieve.

```
string test = alarmType;
```

**Update**: if you're using LINQ-To-Sql and you want to find all records where the `Type` is a substring of `alarmType` you can use:

```
var query = db.Alarms
        .Where(a => SqlMethods.Like(alarmType, string.Format("%{0}%", a.Type)))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
string test = alarmType;
var result = db.Alarms.Where(m => alarmType.Contains(m.Type)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query isn't well-formatted. You have:

```
db.Alarms.Where(alarmType.Contains(m => m.Type)).ToList();
```

So the parameter you've passed to `Contains` is a lambda, which isn't what `Contains` takes,

Likeiwse, `Contains` returns a `bool`, so you've passed a `bool` to `Where`, which is also not a parameter type it takes.

What you want is to pass a lambda to `Where`, like so:

```
db.Alarms.Where(m => alarmType.Contains(m.Type)).ToList();
```

Note how now both the `Where` and the `Contains` are being passed parameters of the correct type.